# jquery troubles-- adding strings to a dynamicly called element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm trying to add the string 'url(" ") '  around my a href 'rel' attribute after calling it through jQuery. I just don't know the right syntax. Here is what I have. I tried to put the url("") inside the rel tag, and that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $('#list li a').hover( function(){
        $("#meow").css( "background", $(this).attr('rel') );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What you want to do is called *string concatenation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that for an example anchor element like this:

```
<a href="http://something.com" rel="http://whatever.com">Test</a>
```

You want to extract the `rel` attribute and wrap it in `'url("...")'` so that you end up with this string:

```
'url("http://whatever.com")'
```

Then you can do that as follows:

```
var newString = 'url("' + $(this).attr("rel") + '")';
```

(Obvioulsy that assumes that `this` is the anchor element in question.)

To put that together with the code from your question:

```
$(function() {
   $('#list li a').hover( function(){
       $("#meow").css( "background", 'url("' + $(this).attr('rel') + '")' );
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn, but for some reason my rel attribute keeps coming back undefined? Do I need to preload them and if I did, how would I go about that?

Comment: actually scratch what I said your solution works dandy, a thousand thank you's :)!!!

Answer (score 2):

Like this (thanks @nnnnnn):

```
var thisRel = $(this).attr('rel'),
theURL = 'url("' + thisRel + '")';
$("#meow").css( "background", theURL );
```

Comment: That's not quite right: it assumes there is already a variable called `rel`, and then tries to retrieve an attribute with a name that is the result of the `'url("' + rel + '")'` concatenation - I believe the intention is to retrieve the `'rel'` attribute first and concatenate the result with the `'url("'` stuff.

Comment: Thanks :) , But now I get an error "rel is not defined", any insight?

Comment: try this again, I slightly misunderstood your question and @nnnnnn caught it.  This has been edited to set two vars first.

Comment: I see this is your first post, so as a reminder - if you are satisfied with an answer please 'check' it. Thanks